# How to switch between CSS styles of React components when changing routes?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-router

I have a React app which now has two routes (the main landing page and career page). 
 

I made one reusable `JumbotronResponsive` component and i am rendering that single component as child under `JumbotronLanding` component (for landing page) and as child under `JumbotronCareer` component (for career page). 

Like this

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react'
import { ResponsiveJumbotron } from '../../HOC';
import './jumbotronCareer.css';

export default class JumbotronCareer extends PureComponent {

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <ResponsiveJumbotron/>
      </>
    )
  }
}
```

and this

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
import { ResponsiveJumbotron } from '../../HOC';
import './jumbotronLanding.css';

export default class JumbotronLanding extends PureComponent {

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <ResponsiveJumbotron/>
      </>
    )
  }
}
```

As you can see those parent components have styles in which i want to style some `ResponsiveJumbotron`'s parts. 
 
For example i wish font-size of jumbotron in landing page be `70px` and in career page be `45px`. 
 
But when i switch between routes those styles are like in one CSS file.  
The question is 'how to separate them from each other?'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a className property and in your ResponsiveJumbotron use it like

```
const ResponsiveJumbotron = props => <div className={props.className} />;

[...] 

export default class JumbotronLanding extends PureComponent {

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <ResponsiveJumbotron className="landing-page" />
      </>
    )
  }
}
```

and you can use that css class in your stylesheet